# PHP script to log the raw data of a POST

Tags: php, post, logging

I am sending data using the HTTP [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) verb . But I am not receiving the data server side, despite the client reporting status-code [200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200). I can see the connection, and that the data was successfully sent, however, on the server, the data isn't found, with the log showing only the number of bytes.

How can I log the raw [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) data that was sent to the server?

FYI, here the client is an embedded device with very limited capability, so this is a problem. I can not check [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r) or [echo](https://www.php.net/echo).

Comment: What happens if you try a print_r($_POST)?

Comment: unfortunately I can not see that in client side. So,it will not work.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the problem with some other client that is more potent (and able to run things like firebug ^^)?

Comment: Wait - so it's a closed server (you cannot get access) you're sending data but you don't know why it's not showing?  This is a black box problem - the software could be doing ANYTHING to your data including ignoring it, storing it somewhere else, encoding it, cleaning the kitchen sink with it - this isn't a PHP or MySQL question in that case.

Comment: @Rudi - I don't think that he's on a closed server. Just the problem that any debugging information can only be output to either some data storage (SQL, file, ...) or to the caller (who is unable to display that data).

Comment: yeah, that's right. Thanks Martin. Sorry, I forgot to respond on Rudi's comment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can see the content of any data sent with the *post* verb (not for production) with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

If you want to see data from the verbs *get*, *post*, *cookie*:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

If you need to log, since the client is very limited - try outputting the *post* data to a file:

```
file_put_contents("post.log", print_r($_POST, true));
file_put_contents("gpc.log", print_r($_REQUEST, true));
```

Comment: Thanks Rudi, I guess file_put_contents is the best thing to do.

Comment: This is really nice and helped answer, :) thanks

Answer (score 15):

Write post data to a file:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/postdata.txt', var_export($_POST, true));
```

Comment: Although this is only acceptable for debugging. Never let anyone write anything that comes from a $_POST directly to some file in real world apps...

Comment: Thank you very much Sjoerd. I guess this is the best thing to do. Since Rudi replied the same before you, so I will have to select his answer :(

Comment: Martin, I understood. I will only use it for debugging

Comment: Great!You just saved my weeks of time :)

Answer (score 4):

To get the raw post from php you must use `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

This will allow you to capture the raw body of the request, instead of form-data only (`$_POST`).

That said, you can use

```php
file_put_contents("post.log", file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

This will allow you to log POST requests with Json data, and other stuff in its body.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [sniffing the HTTP session](http://linuxonly.nl/docs/38/122_Introduction.html).