# php script to echo a post

Tags: php, android

Could someone help with a simple PHP script to echo the whole message received with an HTTPPOST.

I am sending a string from an android app using HTTPPOST and would like to receive as a response the message received by the POST at the server.

The script that I am using will only echo name value pairs

```
echo $_POST('data')
```

works when I post form data, but have not figured out how to echo a string.

Thanks

Comment: This is a lot like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718307/php-script-to-log-the-raw-data-of-post/3718333#3718333 except echo instead of output (if you search the site there are also lots of other questions along this line)

Comment: Could just be a typo while entering here, but your sample is trying to use a variable function call. proper syntax is `$_POST['data']` (note the square brackets).

Comment: It's a typo, thanks the script has [ ]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Possibly more easily parseble:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
echo serialize($_POST);
```

For debugging purposes:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```