# Logging POST requests

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I've scoured the internet and have only been able to find outdated useless 4+ year old guides or have hit dead ends with other solutions. My server OS is Linux Ubuntu 15.04.

Firstly, I've tried using [mod_dumpio](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html), but for the life of me I can't get it to work. Whether its because im missing something, the guides are extremely outdated or its not functional anymore im not sure anymore. I've also tried a different tactic [where the post requests goes to a php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718307/php-script-to-log-the-raw-data-of-post) which is meant to write it to a log, once again to no avail.

Any guidance would be fantastic - really drawn a blank

Comment: Share the code that you've written that doesn't work, then someone might be able to tell you _why_ it doesn't work.

Comment: I linked the php code I gave a whirl - with the mod_dumpio method its 'in  theory' done to just installing a module and changing some config variables 0 ill edit it with a more detailed method on how I approached both methods though